Issue while parsing a C file containing asm() method
I am using Antlr to generate the parser and lexer for C. I have an input code that contains the following snippet.
int coretimer(void){ 
    return _CP0_GET_COUNT();
}

void wait_msec(int msec){
    int endtime=coretimer()+msec*47727;
    while(0<(endtime-(int)coretimer()));
}
void wait60thsec(unsigned short n){
    n+=drawcount;
    while(drawcount!=n) asm("wait");
}

int coretimer(void){ 
    return _CP0_GET_COUNT();
}

void wait_msec(int msec){
    int endtime=coretimer()+msec*47727;
    while(0<(endtime-(int)coretimer()));
}

In this I am having the following errors thrown by Antlrline 173:0 extraneous input 'void' expecting {'extension', '\__builtin_va_arg', '\__builtin_offsetof', '\__as...andline 173:15 no viable alternative at input 'wait_msec(int'
iterationStatement
    : While '(' expression ')' statement
    | Do statement While '(' expression ')' ';'
    | For '(' forCondition ')' statement
    ;

The above is the iteration statement in C.
I think the issue is with parsing the asm("wait"). What change should I make to G4 file to parser the input file successfully? There is an asm block in  G4iterationStatement: While '(' expression ')' AsmBlock?  statement?| Do statement While '(' expression ')' ';'| For '(' forCondition ')' statement;
I tried adding the Asmblock to the while loop but still it is not able to parse it.

I assume that you are referring to the grammars-v4/c grammar. Please enter an Issue so a fix can be tracked.

wouldn't n+=drawcount;     while(drawcount!=n) asm("wait"); wait forever?
